# Decoding input paramters throws invalidity error

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, nodejs, logs

Using the abi for a smart contract that I got, I was trying to decode the input parameters for a transaction receipt using **web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter**s function. The logs.json file is as below:

```
{
  "blockHash": "0x05578d94e81075639f393dd1252deda65c6ab244e399073b6ff946d26af0dce7",
  "blockNumber": 8945008,
  "contractAddress": "0x0E3A2A1f2146d86A604adc220b4967A898D7Fe07",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 9263902,
  "from": "0xef536c805482FeB3D838426ED48320f77FD5F82b",
  "gasUsed": 6928008,
  "logs": [
    {
      "address": "0x0E3A2A1f2146d86A604adc220b4967A898D7Fe07",
      "topics": [
        "0x8be0079c531659141344cd1fd0a4f28419497f9722a3daafe3b4186f6b6457e0",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x000000000000000000000000ef536c805482feb3d838426ed48320f77fd5f82b"
      ],
      "data": "0x",
      "blockNumber": 8945008,
      "transactionHash": "0xc599d6ea2e6d4bd9d908f887a46040338105c20d2e8a08bc457b75180a660f17",
      "transactionIndex": 28,
      "blockHash": "0x05578d94e81075639f393dd1252deda65c6ab244e399073b6ff946d26af0dce7",
      "logIndex": 38,
      "removed": false
    }
  ],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000400000000000000000020000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000001000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": 1,
  "to": null,
  "transactionHash": "0xc599d6ea2e6d4bd9d908f887a46040338105c20d2e8a08bc457b75180a660f17",
  "transactionIndex": 28
}
```

The abi of the function **OwnershipTransferred** which was called as the first topic is

```
{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "previousOwner",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "newOwner",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
    "type": "event"
  }
]
```

The line where I try to decode data is

```
let value = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(['address', 'address'], '0x');
console.log(value);
```

And finally the error that I get is

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/ethereumpc1/Desktop/abi_extraction/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:332:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ethereumpc1/Desktop/abi_extraction/index.js:28:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ABI the event has two parameters that are indexed. The indexed parameters are not included in data field but in the topics array.

```
      "topics": [
        "0x8be0079c531659141344cd1fd0a4f28419497f9722a3daafe3b4186f6b6457e0",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x000000000000000000000000ef536c805482feb3d838426ed48320f77fd5f82b"
      ],
```

The first element is the event signature, the next two are your parameters.

If you want to decode an event log entry I'll suggest to use [`web3.eth.abi.decodeLog`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog) instead. It should be easier and error proof if event abi changes.

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(eventABI, data, topics);
```

Comment: If a transaction didn't trigger an event and hence the creation of topics, then how can we decode the input data or data?

Comment: @mahamzaidi That will be better as a separate question. It is possible to examine input field from transaction but it will require the full abi.

Comment: Yes I already asked separately.